# Get and Send file with PHP and RESTful API

Tags: php, json, api, http

One of my partners has an API service which should send an HTTP POST request whenever a new file is published. This requires me to have an api file which will get the POST this way:

```
http://myip:port/api/ReciveFile
```

and requesting that the JSON format request should be:

```
{
    "FILE ":"filename.zip",
    "FILE_ID":"123",
    "FILE_DESC":"PRUPOUS_FILE",
    "EXTRAVAR":"",
    "EXTRAVAR2":"",
    "USERID":" xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "PASSWORD":"yyyyyyyyyyy"
}
```

Meanwhile it should issue a response, in JSON format if it got the file or not

```
{"RESULT_CODE":0,"RESULT_DESCR":""}
{"RESULT_CODE":1001,"RESULT_DESCR":"Bad request"}
```

And after, when I am finished elaborating the file, I should send back the modified file same way.

The question is, now basically from what I understand he will send me the variables witch I have to read, download the file, and send a response back.

I am not really sure how to do this any sample code would be welcomed!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well might seem foolish, but i dont have any idea how to do this .. @AnthonyGarcia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the question is, but if you mean creating a success response in JSON for if an action occurred while adding data to it which is what can be understood from the question, just create an array with the values you wish to send back to the provider and do `json_encode` on the array which should create json and just print it back as a response.

About receiving the information; all you have to do is use the integrated `curl` functions or use a wrapper (Guzzle, etc) to output the raw JSON or `json_decode` data into a variable and do whatever you please with it.

From what I read in the question, you wish to modify the contents of it. This can be achieved by just decoding the json and changing the variables in the array, then printing the modified JSON back as a response.

Example (this uses GuzzleHTTP as an example):

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'url');
$json = $res->getBody();
$array = json_decode($json, 1); // decode the json
// Start modifying the values or adding
$array['value_to_modify'] = $whatever;
$filename = $array['filename']; // get filename
// make a new request
$res = $client->request('GET', 'url/'.$filename);
// get the body of specified filename
$body = $res->getBody();
// Return the array.
echo json_encode($body);
```

References:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

Comment: Yes the question is I dont know how to archive this, if you could give a pratical example i could follow it would be really nice @sergio-e-diaz

Comment: @BlediShehu I'll try to give a pseudo-code example in a bit.

Comment: The main idea is that he is sending me the filename in json, and i have to download it and send a response if everything went through ok, 

In the request there should be the User And Pass to i think @sergio-e-diaz